# SQL return data based on checkbox values

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains following columns:

```
[Id], [Name], [Shampoo], [ShowerGel], [HairConditioner]
```

The `[Shampoo]`, `[ShowerGel]` and `[HairConditioner]` columns specify the type of the entry.

I also have three checkboxes (`bit` variables) that tell whether I want to display specific entry or all of them.

For example, if only the `ShowerGel` checkbox is checked, then return values that belong to the type of `ShowerGel`.

Or if `ShowerGel` and `HairConditioner` checkboxes are checked, then return only the ones that belong to these types.

If all of the checkboxes are checked (or all of them are unchecked), then display all the entries.

*The question is*: how can I achieve it using **ONLY** the `WHERE` clause? If it's even possible.

Any kind of help/tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the datatype of [Shampoo], [ShowerGel] and [HairConditioner] columns, share some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Do you mean you need to pass your three checkbox values into the SQL and have it carry out all of the logic there? You'll need to write lots of brackets, ANDs and ORs: you'll need a case for all three inputs false, OR where one of the inputs is on then you'll need the corresponding table column to be set. Is that enough to get you started?

Comment: @Rup Yes, thats exactly what I mean. I pass the bool/checkbox values from a c# app and then handle all the logic in SQL.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `@Shampoo`, `@ShowerGel` and `@HairConditioner` are variables of type `bit` filled by the checkboxes' values. Further assuming you want to show an item if it matches any type. E.g. if something is a shampoo and a shower gel and the check box for shower gel is checked, but the one for shampoo isn't, show that something anyway.

```
WHERE @Shampoo = 0
      AND @ShowerGel = 0
      AND @HairConditioner = 0
       OR @Shampoo = 1
          AND [Shampoo] = 1
        OR @ShowerGel = 1
           AND [ShowerGel] = 1
         OR @HairConditioner = 1
            AND [HairConditioner] = 1
```

The first three handle the case if all are unchecked. The others the cases where some or all are checked.

Comment: That works exactly how I needed it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the datatype of columns are `bit`, then you can simply have `OR` conditions in `where` clause, like below

```
Declare @IsShampoo bit, @IsShowerGel bit, @IsHairConditioner bit -- Checkbox values
select * 
from @YourTbale
where Shampoo = @IsShampoo
OR ShowerGel = @IsShowerGel
OR HairConditioner = @IsHairConditioner
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It returns all of the groups even when only a single of them is 1/true.

Comment: share some sample data of the table in your question and expected output